# How do you scroll a second window without moving your mouse out of a web page?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, mouse, scrolling, focus

So, some websites I've visited do some tricks with the mouse, especially when you leave a web page.

They detect this and perform some action, like show you an advertisement or force a prompt to the front of the screen.

I like to have two windows side-by-side so this can be a problem; how do I scroll window number 2 without leaving window number 1, the website?

Is it possible to have a duplicate mouse pointer, freeze one and control the other? That would be amazing. I'm sure there's a trick to this but I haven't discovered it yet. Of course, another option is to freeze their detection of mouse movement, so to them it's always pointed. Does this exist?

Comment: Windows has at long last caught up to the idea that you can scroll any page your cursor is hovering over, without needing to bring it to the front. If Chrome hasn't cottoned onto that idea yet, Edge certainly has.

Comment: I'm afraid, in my specific use case, if the mouse leaves what I perceive to be the borders of its canvas, it will trigger an ad or prompt. I haven't found anything to disable mouse tracking without haphazardly disabling all of javascript.